# Can you see what is wrong with this query?

Tags: sql, oracle

Im developing an application in `Grails 2.2.4` and using Groovy, and I have this part of the code:

```
def str2= """select to_number(to_date(NEXTRUNTIME,'DD-MON-YYYY') - to_date(LASTRUNTIME,'DD-MON-YYYY')) as DAYS, SUBSTR(to_CHAR(NEXTRUNTIME,'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS'),13,8)as Hour from v8_recurtimeevent WHERE to_date(NEXTRUNTIME,'DD-MON-YYYY') != to_date(LASTRUNTIME,'DD-MON-YYYY') AND EVENT_UUID='000001112eae40e3-0000-b517-0a40246b';"""
```

```
 sql.eachRow(str2)
 {
     x.date="Days:"+"${it.Days}".toString()+" and hour: "+"${it.Hour}"
 }
```

And when I execute it, I got this errors. Can you see what is the matter?

> URI
>   /JobMigrator/jobA/tableJobs
>   Class
>   java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException
>   Message
>   ORA-00911: invalid character

Comment: First mistake.. `Format`

Comment: Second mistake "Semicolon" in the Query String!

Comment: Thak you, and second?

Comment: Why don't you execute it (or try it) in a SQL editor for you DB? Or do you think asking here is more quick?

Comment: @robermann - in this case it would probably work, as the stray semicolon is allowed elsewhere. But yes, would be nice to be able to see that they'd tried first...

Comment: Actually in Oracle SQL Developer worked perfectly, but here in grails it didn't, I had the answer below, thank you all!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
def str2= "select to_number(TRUNC(NEXTRUNTIME) -
                          TRUNC(LASTRUNTIME)) as DAYS,
                  SUBSTR(to_CHAR(NEXTRUNTIME,'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS'),13,8)as Hour
           from v8_recurtimeevent
           WHERE TRUNC(NEXTRUNTIME) != TRUNC(LASTRUNTIME)
             AND EVENT_UUID='000001112eae40e3-0000-b517-0a40246b'"
```

Also , TRUNC() is what you needed! to ignore the time element in the date!

Comment: The `to_number` is superfluous as well; and the `substr` wouldn't be needed if the date format mask was just `HH24:MI:SS`. But you can only fix so much... *8-)

Comment: I optimizated it! Thanks!